# Excel: How to Sort or filter text by specific word or words?

Tags: excel, sorting, filter

[Order text by finding the word elephant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO1In.png)

Is it possible to order/sort/filter a column based on a specific word even if the word is in a sentence in the cell. For example in my image I'd like to order the column by the word elephant. So the cell with elephant will be at the top. Or better yet , order/filter/sort the column by two word in the same sentence e.g. elephant&dog in the cell with Tower&elephant&dog

Is that possible and how? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

**Fast - Max 2 Filter Criteria**

You just need to apply a custom filter, and then choose contains. To do this, with no filter applied yet, click top left corner right click it and choose Filter | Filter by Selected Cells Value.

You can add multiple entries using the OR option for multiple words:

Contains | dog
OR
Contains | cat

[image]

[image]

**Greater than 2 Filter Critiera**, use Advanced:

1. Set up your criteria range. The header must be named exactly like the column where Excel should apply your filter to (data table in example)
2. Select your whole table (A1:A11 in example)
3. Go to: `Menu Bar » Data » Filter » Advanced`
4. Select your whole criteria range including the header under Criteria range (C1:C4 in example)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. What if I want more than one word e.g. dog and cat and elephant. So it'll filter by that criteria

Answer (score 0):

In an unused column to the right, set up a 'helper' column. In the same row as the first row of data (e.g. B3) use this formula,

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Elephant","Dog"}, A3)))
```

Fill down as necessary. Sort on the 'helper' column as the primary key and *<optionally>* any other important column(s) as secondary sort keys.

[image: sort_helper_before]
                     <sup>Data set up with 'Helper' column</sup>

[image: sort_helper_after]
                     <sup>After sorting on the 'Helper' column descending</sup>

Comment: Actually, sadly this doens't help. I think i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't know what has to do with sorting but if you're happy, I can consider the matter closed.